# Make only two routes with https protocol in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I want only my payment checkout pages in https. I have a website in http://, I´m implement a payment checkout with Stripe credit card, but Stripe only works with https...

I want that all my website have http, except the /payment-date page and the payment-data-post page, to send the data to Stripe with secure protocol.

How I can have only those two pages on https?

The routes are:

```
Route::get('/payment-data',['as'=> 'payment_data','uses' => 'WebController@getPaymentData']);

Route::post('/post-payment-data', ['as'  => 'post_payment_data', 'uses' => 'WebController@postPaymentData']);
```

**I want only this routes in https**

The framework is Laravel 5.3

Comment: There's no reason not to have your entire website under https.

Comment: Believe me, I have many reasons, so I ask here...

Comment: Maybe this helps http://laravel.io/forum/12-26-2014-routing-with-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good practice would be to create a Middleware which you then can use on whatever routes you'd like.

Using your Terminal, navigate to your project’s root directory and issue the following artisan command *(to create ForceHttpProtocol middleware)*:

```
php artisan make:middleware ForceHttpProtocol
```

Change the newly created /app/Http/Middleware/ForceHttpProtocol.php so it looks something like this (will work only on production):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ForceHttpProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'pro') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Next step is to update **/app/Http/Kernel.php** by adding the **'App\Http\Middleware\ForceHttpProtocol'** which will make Laravel aware of your custom middleware.

---

If you want to apply middleware only on specific routes, you just have to assign middleware to routes by adding 'App\Http\Middleware\ForceHttpProtocol' instruction to $routeMiddleware array.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ...
    'forceSSL' => App\Http\Middleware\ForceHttpProtocol::class,

];
```

Just use the newly created middleware as you’re used to:

```
Route::get('payment-date', ['middleware' => 'forceSSL', function()
{
   // do stuff
}]);
```

That should be it!

Comment: Ok,I will try this code, Is not it better to create a route group? Like this `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','forceSSL']], function ()
{
    Route::get('/payment-data',['as'=> 'payment_data','uses' => 'WebController@getPaymentData']);

    Route::post('/post-payment-data', ['as'  => 'post_payment_data', 'uses' => 'WebController@postPaymentData']);
}`

Comment: Sure, you can use a route group and just apply the middlewares you'd like to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify if routes should be HTTP or HTTPS by passing ['http' => true] or ['https' => true] as options when declaring your routes, if you don't specify those options then it should just use the same protocol as you're currently accessing the page with.

```
Route::post('/form', ['uses' => 'FormController@postForm', 'https' => true]);
```

Comment: Mmm this works in Laravel 5.3?, the people says that not working